# How can I debug async

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This question might me really easy, but I really don't understand how to do it.

I've created a class with multiple methods that call each other (first one does some logic and then calls the second one and so on). All these methods are async due to await to POST and GET method from outside server.

I want to debug my work, to see how it works on each stage and where have I gone wrong, but I don't know how. I've tried calling the first function directly from the main function and add a break point, but got yield that "await" is missing, and after addin "await" I'm getting yield that I need to make the method async, which contradict my purpose.

What can I do?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    await LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync();
}
```

All I want is to follow the process of `LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync`.

Comment: You nee to make your `LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync()` return Task or Task<T> if you want to await it.and you need to make your Main async or you cannot call the await inside it.

Comment: I simply want to debug it. And it is already returning a Task .@JordyvanEijk

Comment: You need to be more specific at what you want to debug. If you put a breakpoint inside `LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync` you will hit it. If you run in debug mode

Comment: Just put the breakpoint after/within the async function. You cannot hit it from the outside function by going a line at a time. But if you break before the async and you have another breakpoint inside the async and hit continue. It will hit the other breakpoint.

Comment: @Yossi - Did you just delete your new question because the `catch (Exception ex)` was the culprit?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thought it was, undeleted it , still the same happens .

Comment: Please, read about how to correctly call async methods: https://www.recaffeinate.co/post/how-to-await-console-application/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Please try the following

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Run();
    }

    private async void Run()
    {
        await LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync();
    }

    private static Task LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync()
    {
        //Put breakpoint here!
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and put a breakpoint inside the `LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync()`
this will hit the breakpoint

Comment: Not if the program terminated before the break point is hit. `Run` returns immediatly if the `Task` returned by `LoadCampaignTemplete...` is not completed, so `Main` returns and the process terminates....

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future. This isn't a good answer.

Comment: @RenéVogt is right, if the Run is done it will not hit the breakpoint anymore. But if you do more work it shoulld probably hit the breakpoint. Or you can wait on the result before continuing.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to call async method from Main would be calling `Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync().Result;
    LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Also, starting from C# 7.1 you can make Main async:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await LoadCampaignTempleteJSONAsync();
}
```

Comment: Note: Always use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Using just `Result` will deadlock. Also, `async Main` is just syntactic sugar. Under the hood, the compiler simply defines a regular `Main` and the calls your `async Main` from that, using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm having hard time understanding why it would deadlock. First of all this is a Console Application. Console Applications don't have SynchronizationContext so there is no real way of deadlocking when returning from awaited task. Secondly, `Result` is almost identical to `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in its implementation. The only difference is that `Result` wraps every exception in `AggregateException` which is annoying when debugging.

Comment: Telling people it's safe to use `Result` in some instances and not others is a recipe for disaster, when they can just always use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and be fine all the time. And, you then always get proper exceptions as a bonus.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The point is that `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will deadlock. Create **WPF** application with async method `async Task<int> DoWorkAsync() { await Task.Delay(5); return 1; } ` and then try to wait for it synchronously with `DoWorkAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. This will be the longest 5 ms in your life.

Comment: GetAwaiter().GetResult(); works in console app, but does it work for multiple calls or in Web Application?